# Is there a way to disable the 3d buildings view in a basic map? Javascript HERE MAPS

Tags: javascript, angular, here-api, here-maps-rest

I’ve been digging around the documentation but haven’t found anything about this.
Is there a way to disable the 3d buildings view in a basic map?

Right now I get the following view:
[map view with 3d? buildings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VICz.png)

But I’d like to see it in a much cleaner way as the image below:
[desired buildings look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pe6iZ.png)

Greetings and thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code should disable building's extrusion, so only building's base is rendered.

```
let cfg = map.getBaseLayer().getProvider().getStyle().extractConfig('buildings.extrude');

cfg.layers.buildings.extrude['visible'] = false;

map.getBaseLayer().getProvider().getStyle().mergeConfig(cfg);
```

For more information see [vector map styling user guide](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/dev_guide/topics/vector.html)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Just had to place it in the ngAfterViewInit after the map was correctly initialized.

Thanks a lot, I was a bit lost in here.